# Upgrade from 12.10 to the new 13.04 Ubuntu OS

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, 13.04, inspiron

What is the best way to upgrade your distro with Ubuntu? I am currently using a LVM partition booting with UEFI boot firmware. Last time I upgraded my Distro, I couldn't boot up. I am using a Dell Inspiron 7520, and I am issuing troubles with my graphic because it is a Intel/ATI hybrid.

I just want to know what would be the best way to upgrade my distro without having to reinstall the whole thing again.

Thank You =)